# How to make use of an SVG image in Qt stylesheet

Tags: qt, user-interface, svg, stylesheet

I'm trying to use an SVG image as the image for my buttons. The reason I'm using SVG is because the sizes of my buttons vary. However, when I use it in my stylesheet, the svg image isn't stretched according to the button's size.

How do you make it resize according to button's size in Qt stylesheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QT: creating an "svg image button"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815581/qt-creating-an-svg-image-button)

Comment: I've seen this link. What I'm looking for is a way to get it stretched using just "QT stylesheet" and without having to modify the code of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured how to... just use border-image in your qt stylesheet... (^^,) .. no need to modify your code...